# Erro ao tentar fazer inserção SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Criei uma tabela no BD com o seguinte código

```
CREATE TABLE documentosDefesa
(
id_documentos_defesa int NOT NULL,
id_reclamatoria int NOT NULL,
funcao nvarchar(50) NULL
);
```

E agora quando tento fazer a seguinte inserção,:

```
INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[documentosDefesa] (id_reclamatoria, funcao) VALUES (177,'Pedreiro')
```

no SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT ele apresenta o seguinte aviso:

Não é possível inserir o valor NULL na coluna 'id_documentos_defesa', tabela 'RDO.dbo.documentosDefesa'; a coluna não permite nulos. Falha em INSERT.

Eu não entendo o por que desse erro, pois não é a primeira vez que crio uma tabela e faço isso!

Comment: Esse campo é `identity`?

Comment: O campo foi criado como `int NOT NULL` logo não pode ser *null*. Julgo que deveria ser declarado como `identity` e não `int`

Comment: Não... Como devo proceder então? Altero o campo para int identity?

Comment: Mas o próprio sistema quem se encarrega de colocar valor nesse campo, certo?

Comment: Sim, se for `identity`

Comment: Certo.
Então, é só eu alterar o campo? Colocar o identity?

Comment: Tem de ser declarado assim: `id_documentos_defesa int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,`

Comment: Valeu pessoal, deu certo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do jeito que criaste a tua tabela, está definido que o campo id_documentos_defesa não pode ser nulo, e na hora de inserir, não estás a especificar valor para tal campo (que não pode ser nulo).

Se calhar, esperavas que este campo fosse auto-incrementado. Para isso, terias que criar a tua tabela da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE documentosDefesa
(
    id_documentos_defesa int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    id_reclamatoria int NOT NULL,
    funcao nvarchar(50) NULL
);
```

Ou então, mudar o instrução SQL. por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[documentosDefesa] (id_documentos_defesa, id_reclamatoria, funcao) VALUES (1, 177,'Pedreiro')
```

Se não quiseres eliminar a tabela toda, podes alterar apenas a coluna de ID:

```
ALTER TABLE documentosDefesa DROP COLUMN id_documentos_defesa;
ALTER TABLE documentosDefesa ADD id_documentos_defesa int IDENTITY(1,1);
```

Comment: Mas é para o sistema colocar valor de id nessa campos @P. Santos, não eu hehehe

Comment: Mas é isso que a resposta ensina a fazer, @Gustavo.